# How do I grab data from a Google API for an autocomplete field in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My ultimate goal is to have a text field on the homepage of the site that listens for typing and on each keystroke grabs data from Google's Places API and posts the list to the homepage. I am currently trying to use a computed property for this, but seem to be running into an issue with the binding not waiting for the API request to return.

I've been reading up on Promises, but am not sure on how to incorporate them into my controller.

This is my current attempt:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend
  service: new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService()
  searchText: ''

  searchResults: (->
    # service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService()
    @get('service').getPlacePredictions({input: @get('searchText')}, (predictions, status)->
      console.log(predictions)
    )
  ).property('searchText')
```

The console logs the result properly, but the searchResults property doesn't get updated.

My questions are how can I get the bindings to update after the API request is successful, and is this an optimal way to organize this logic?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Ember Data accepts a promise as value of a property, but you can try testing that by wrapping `google.maps.places.AutocompleteService` response in an RSVP promise.

Here is another solution that should work. Particularly notice fat arrow and `@set`.

```
searchResults: (->
  @get('service').getPlacePredictions({input: @get('searchText')}, (predictions, status)=>
    @set('searchResults', predictions)
  )
).property('searchText')
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the hints by Pooyan, this is what I ended up going with:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend
  service: new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService()
  searchText: ''
  results: null

  searchTextChanged: (->
    if @get('searchText').length
      @get('service').getPlacePredictions({input: @get('searchText')}, (predictions, status) =>
        console.log("update map here...")
        @set('results', predictions)
      )
    else
      @set('results', null)
  ).observes('searchText')
```

Basically, I used an observer to keep an eye on my text field. When the text field changes, we make a call to Google's service which fetches the results. We then set those results to the results property.

Comment: Did you try returning a promise from property declaration? This is a better approach if it works, if it does not, I'm sure you can send a PR to Ember Data repo for it and they'll accept.

Comment: @PooyanKhosravi, I'm not sure how this would be setup exactly. Could you show an example?